# Treat Digit as Number

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Given the following code:

```
var n = '1';
var x = n + 2;
```

`x` is set to "12".

Assuming I cannot change the value of `n`, what the most efficient way to have `x` set to 3?

Is it necessary to use `parseInt()` here? Or is there a way to have JavaScript automatically treat the digit as a number?

Comment: If you are using parseInt() dont forget the second parameter 10 like     parseInt(n,10)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not an exact duplicate. As my question points out, I already know about `parseInt()`. My question is if there is a way to simply have JavaScript treat the digit to be a number in the way it treated a number as a digit in the code example in my question, without explicitly parsing the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt(n,10)` would work. You can also do `n^0` as a shortcut. In fact, there are several such shortcuts available, but `parseInt` is "best" because it's more obvious to a human reader.

Comment: I find unary plus quite readable

Comment: Xor zero is nice as well, I admit

Answer (score 4):

You can add `+` before `n`, this way it will parse it to a number.

```
var x = +n + 2;
```